# Overwrite Wordpress plugin function for translation

Tags: php, wordpress

My WP theme comes with a function that shows working hours, the name of the days are hardcoded in the script, I'd like to translate them without editing the plugin files.

**PLUGIN CODE**

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists( 'montagne_core_include_working_hours_shortcodes' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that includes shortcodes
     */
    function montagne_core_include_working_hours_shortcodes() {
        foreach ( glob( MONTAGNE_CORE_INC_PATH . '/working-hours/shortcodes/*/include.php' ) as $shortcode ) {
            include_once $shortcode;
        }
    }

    add_action( 'qode_framework_action_before_shortcodes_register', 'montagne_core_include_working_hours_shortcodes' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'montagne_core_include_working_hours_widgets' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that includes widgets
     */
    function montagne_core_include_working_hours_widgets() {
        foreach ( glob( MONTAGNE_CORE_INC_PATH . '/working-hours/shortcodes/*/widget/include.php' ) as $widget ) {
            include_once $widget;
        }
    }

    add_action( 'qode_framework_action_before_widgets_register', 'montagne_core_include_working_hours_widgets' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'montagne_core_set_working_hours_template_params' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that set working hours area content parameters
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function montagne_core_set_working_hours_template_params( $params ) {
        $days = array(
            'monday'    => esc_html__( 'Monday', 'montagne-core' ),
            'tuesday'   => esc_html__( 'Tuesday', 'montagne-core' ),
            'wednesday' => esc_html__( 'Wednesday', 'montagne-core' ),
            'thursday'  => esc_html__( 'Thursday', 'montagne-core' ),
            'friday'    => esc_html__( 'Friday', 'montagne-core' ),
            'saturday'  => esc_html__( 'Saturday', 'montagne-core' ),
            'sunday'    => esc_html__( 'Sunday', 'montagne-core' ),
        );

        foreach ( $days as $day => $label ) {
            $option = montagne_core_get_post_value_through_levels( 'qodef_working_hours_' . $day );

            $params[ $day ] = ! empty( $option ) ? esc_attr( $option ) : '';
        }

        return $params;
    }

    add_filter( 'montagne_core_filter_working_hours_template_params', 'montagne_core_set_working_hours_template_params' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'montagne_core_set_working_hours_special_template_params' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that set working hours area special content parameters
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function montagne_core_set_working_hours_special_template_params( $params ) {
        $special_days = montagne_core_get_post_value_through_levels( 'qodef_working_hours_special_days' );
        $special_text = montagne_core_get_post_value_through_levels( 'qodef_working_hours_special_text' );

        if ( ! empty( $special_days ) ) {
            $special_days = array_filter( (array) $special_days, 'strlen' );
        }

        $params['special_days'] = $special_days;
        $params['special_text'] = esc_attr( $special_text );

        return $params;
    }

    add_filter( 'montagne_core_filter_working_hours_special_template_params', 'montagne_core_set_working_hours_special_template_params' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'montagne_core_working_hours_set_admin_options_map_position' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that set dashboard admin options map position for this module
     *
     * @param int $position
     * @param string $map
     *
     * @return int
     */
    function montagne_core_working_hours_set_admin_options_map_position( $position, $map ) {

        if ( 'working-hours' === $map ) {
            $position = 90;
        }

        return $position;
    }

    add_filter( 'montagne_core_filter_admin_options_map_position', 'montagne_core_working_hours_set_admin_options_map_position', 10, 2 );
}
```

This is how they are displayed in the HTML, using `<?php echo esc_html( $day ); ?>`:

```
<div <?php qode_framework_class_attribute( $holder_classes ); ?>>
    <?php foreach ( $params['working_hours_params'] as $day => $time ) : ?>
        <div class="qodef-working-hours-item qodef-e">
            <?php if ( ! empty( $day ) ) : ?>
                <h6 class="qodef-e-day"><?php echo esc_html( $day ); ?>
                    <?php
                    foreach ( $params['working_hours_special_params']['special_days'] as $special ) :
                        if ( $day === $special ) :
                            echo qode_framework_icons()->render_icon( 'icon_star', 'elegant-icons', array( 'icon_attributes' => array( 'class' => 'qodef-e-day-icon' ) ) );
                        endif;
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </h6>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="qodef-e-line"></div>
            <?php if ( ! empty( $time ) ) { ?>
                <h6 class="qodef-e-time"><?php echo esc_html( $time ); ?></h6>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <h6 class="qodef-e-time qodef--closed"><?php esc_html_e( 'Closed', 'montagne-core' ); ?></h6>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div class="qodef-m-footer">
        <?php if ( isset( $params['working_hours_special_params']['special_text'] ) && ! empty( $params['working_hours_special_params']['special_text'] ) ) : ?>
            <span class="qodef-m-footer-label"><?php echo esc_html( $params['working_hours_special_params']['special_text'] ); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo qode_framework_icons()->render_icon( 'icon_star', 'elegant-icons', array( 'icon_attributes' => array( 'class' => 'qodef-m-footer-icon' ) ) ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried replacing the function in my functions.php but I still see the english ones:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'montagne_core_set_working_hours_template_params' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that set working hours area content parameters
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function montagne_core_set_working_hours_template_params( $params ) {
        $days = array(
            'lunedì'    => custom_translate( 'Lunedì' ),
            'martedì'   => custom_translate( 'Martedì' ),
            'mercoledì' => custom_translate( 'Mercoledì' ),
            'giovedì'  => custom_translate( 'Giovedì' ),
            'venerdì'    => custom_translate( 'Venerdì' ),
            'sabato'  => custom_translate( 'Sabato' ),
            'domenica'    => custom_translate( 'Domenica' ),
        );

        foreach ( $days as $day => $label ) {
            $option = montagne_core_get_post_value_through_levels( 'qodef_working_hours_' . $day );

            $params[ $day ] = ! empty( $option ) ? esc_attr( $option ) : '';
        }

        return $params;
    }

    add_filter( 'montagne_core_filter_working_hours_template_params', 'montagne_core_set_working_hours_template_params' );

    /**
     * Custom translation function
     *
     * @param string $text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function custom_translate( $text ) {
        return esc_html__( $text, 'montagne-core' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Although not what you are asking for, I just wanted to make sure that you are aware that for this very specific use-case, core has a method called [`get_weekday`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_locale/get_weekday/) that is locale-aware. To get the localized version of Sunday you'd do: `global $wp_locale; echo $wp_locale->get_weekday(0);`

Comment: _"the name of the days are hardcoded in the script"_ - not sure if it makes much sense to try and translate those array _keys_ - depending on what those are used for afterwards, it simply might not work any more as intended. The array _values_ however are made translatable already - so that is probably what you should look into, create a proper translation file for the text domain `montagne-core` for your desired target language, and place it in one of the appropriate locations.

Comment: @CBroe problem is that this theme part comes from a "framework" plugin, so I'm not sure how to get it translated when displayed, unfotunately it does not comes from the theme.

Comment: It doesn't have to "come from the theme", you just need to provide a translation file for the used text domain. If the plugin itself is not prepared to look for the translation file outside of its own folder, then you can use the `load_textdomain_mofile` hook to overwrite this, https://www.wpastronaut.com/blog/overwriting-wordpress-translations/

Comment: @CBroe i tried but the template prints the key of the variable, not the name or the translated name. I can translate Monday to another language but in HTML it will always be displayed "monday".

Comment: Rather something the plugin author should fix then. Your attempt likely did not work, because of the execution order - see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622 Plugin code gets executed, before the functions.php - so your `if ( ! function_exists(...)` checks will likely not your code do nothing, because the functions _do_ already exist.